# HTTP Connection errors in android eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I am trying to send user phone number which he inputs in application to my localhost database using this code:

```
Submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            InputStream is=null;

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                //Storing the values inside the EditText inside the String Variable
                String PhoneNumber=""+etPhoneNumber.getText().toString();

                //Setting Up the nameValuePairs
                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs =new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);

                //Adding the string variable inside the NameValuePair
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("PhoneNumber", PhoneNumber));

                //Setting Up the Connection inside the try catch block
                try {
                    //Setting up the default http client
                    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.15.210/index.php");

                    //passing the name pair variables inside the httpPost
                    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                    //Getting the response
                    HttpResponse response =httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                    Log.i("Tag","nameValuePairs");

                    //setting up the http response
                    HttpEntity entity =response.getEntity();

                    //Setting up the content inside an input stream reader
                    //Lets define the input stream reader
                    is = entity.getContent();

                    //Displaying the Toast msg if the data is entered successfully
                    String msg="Data is entered successfully";
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } catch(ClientProtocolException e) {
                    Log.e("ClientProtocol","Log_tag");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch(IOException e) {
                    Log.e("Log_tag","IOException");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

LogCat:

```
07-08 03:33:14.138: W/System.err(23711): org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://192.168.15.210 refused
07-08 03:33:14.170: W/System.err(23711):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:183)
07-08 03:33:14.170: W/System.err(23711):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
07-08 03:33:14.170: W/System.err(23711):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
07-08 03:33:14.170: W/System.err(23711):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:365)
07-08 03:33:14.170: W/System.err(23711):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
07-08 03:33:14.170: W/System.err(23711):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
07-08 03:33:14.170: W/System.err(23711):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
07-08 03:33:14.172: W/System.err(23711):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:181)
07-08 03:33:14.175: W/System.err(23711):    at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:119)
07-08 03:33:14.175: W/System.err(23711):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:144)
```

Comment: Don't run network operations on `mainThread`. And make sure you have internet permission in your manifest file

Comment: i have added these lines in main activity :
 ' //StricTPolicy
  StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy= new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
  StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); ' 
so it wouldnt restrict network connections in main thread , still doesn't work